# git svn is only converting the last commit

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a repository which is structured as follows:

```
project/trunk
project/branches
project/tags
project/cms
```

If I do:

```
git svn clone svn://svnurl/svn/project/cms --no-metadata -A ~/tmp/tools/gitsvn_authors/master_gitsvn_format.txt cms
```

It converts ok, but it only takes the last commit of the 'cms' project. There is no history past the last commit. cms does not have a standard layout. It doesn't have any trunk/branches/tags.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you want.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I am using svn2git for larger projects with longer history. In this case though the project is very small, and it is quicker to use 'git svn'. The project is not active and is quite old, so I am not overly concerned about branches/tags etc.

Comment: Actually I don't think size does matter, but KDE `svn2git` is always preferable, especially if you already have it set up and thus have no ramp up time. Then using `git svn` also is not really quicker. :-) Besides that, your command should usually have gotten the whole history and I think it is hard to diagnose the problem without seeing the actual SVN repo.